# Gulp exclude files from a stream if they exist in destination

Tags: gulp

How would I exclude files from a stream if they exist in a destination. Or, alternatively, how do I tell `gulp.dest()` not to overwrite files if they exist?

Answer (score 1):

**gulp-conflict**

> Check if files in stream conflict with those in target dir, with
>   option to use new, keep old, show diff, etc.

https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-conflict/

Comment: From what I can tell, this provides the user with a choice, which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 1):

The [gulp-changed](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-changed) plug-in may solve your problem. By default it will detect whether files in the stream have changed and you can have it just right those files to the destination. Using the options you should be able to compare the source files to the destination files or supply your own custom comparison function.